# stripe onboarding/Standard accounts import

Tags: flutter, dart, stripe-payments

I want to use stripe onboarding/Standard accounts for my flutter app. However, I don't know what import to use. Is there a import I can use for the Standard accounts? An example is for stripe payment, I use the package:stripe_payment/stripe_payment.dart but for Standard accounts, what import do I use?

Comment: Using Connect is mostly a backend thing(creating/updating/managing account is mainly something you do on your server)  so it's not related to Flutter or any specific import; and it always requires custom coding, not just a drop-in library.

Comment: @karllekko Hi, how would I connect my backend with stripe, I am using firebase as my backend.